# Proof of "$p$-groups are nilpotent" theorem in Rotman's Theory of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I'm reviewing the basics about finite $p$-groups using several books for different perspectives. One familiar fact is that "normalizers grow," meaning that if $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $H$ is a proper subgroup, then $H < N_G(H)$.

My other texts prove this more generally for nilpotent groups, but Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups* (4th edition) tackles it directly in Theorem 4.6. Unfortunately, I can't make heads or tails of the proof:

---

If $H \lhd G$ then $N_G(H) = G$ and the theorem is true. If $X$ is the set of all the conjugates of $H$, then we may assume that $|X| = [G:N_G(H)] \neq 1$. Now $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation and, since $G$ is a $p$-group, every orbit of $X$ has size a power of $p$. As $\{H\}$ is an orbit of size $1$, there must be at least $p-1$ other orbits of size $1$. Thus there is at least one conjugate $gHg^{-1} \neq H$ with $\{gHg^{-1}\}$ also an orbit of size $1$. Now $agHg^{-1}a^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$ for all $a \in H$, and so $g^{-1}ag \in N_G(H)$ for all $a \in H$. But $gHg^{-1} \neq H$ gives at least one $a \in H$ with $g^{-1}ag \not\in H$, and so $N < N_G(H)$.

---

My problem with this proof: If $X$ is the set of all conjugates of $H$, and $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, then isn't this action transitive (i.e., there is only one orbit), almost by definition? The orbit containing $H$ is all of $X$, and it does not have size $1$ unless $H$ is normal, the case which was already handled in the first sentence.

I'm trying to work out how to fix this proof in the spirit intended by the author. But his argument relies on $X$ being the set of conjugates of $H$ and $|X| = [G:N_G(H)]$. The only action I know of with these properties is the one given in the proof.

Comment: I changed the title to match the question, since the proof you have issues with is about showing that $p$-groups are nilpotent; I hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the book here but he probably considers the action of $N_G(H)$ on the conjugates of $H$, this is very different from the action of $G$ on the conjugates of $H$: the latter has (as you noticed) exactly one orbit, but if you restrict yourself to $N_G(H)$ this orbit falls apart into a number of orbits, one of which will be $\{H\}$.

Comment: That was my first thought. However, in that case $|X|$ is not $[G:N_G(H)]$ but rather $[N_G(H):N_{N_G(H)}(H)]$, and it is not obvious to me that this must be greater than $1$.

Comment: The set $X$ is still the same set! It is the set of all conjugates of $H$ under $G$: in symbols $X = \{H^g \mid g\in G\}$, only the group acting on this set is different. In particular, the order is still $[G:N_G(H)]$. But instead of $G$ acting on it, we consider $N_G(H)$ acting on it.

Comment: By the way note that $[N_G(H):N_{N_G(H)}(H)] = 1$, because $N_{N_G(H)}(H) = N_G(H)$. Every element in $N_G(H)$ will normalize $H$, by definition of the normalizer. So in particular the normalizer of $H$ inside its own normalizer is exactly the normalizer.

Comment: Oh, right, that makes sense! I wasn't thinking correctly about the action of $N_G(H)$ on $X$. I think the rest of the proof works OK under this assumption. Thank you!