# How to understand orbit of size $1$ in this case

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am a self-studying beginner in group theory, so please bear with this question which could have some simple answers. Given a $p$-group $G$ for some prime $p$, let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $X$ be the set of all conjugates of $H$.

Now, $H$ acts on $X$ by conjugation. I read that there are at least $p$ orbits of size $1$ in $X$.

One example of an orbit with size $1$ is $\{H\} \in X$. This example follows since $aHa^{-1}=H$ for any $a \in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup, and we have $\text{Orb}(H)=H$.

But I read that since $p$ is prime, that there are at least $p-1$ other orbits of size $1$. So there should be another orbit $gHg^{-1} \neq H$ of size $1$ in $X$.

What I don't understand is how $gHg^{-1}$ could be of size $1$ under the action of $H$. Shouldn't this mean that $\text{Orb}(gHg^{-1})=\{agHg^{-1}a^{-1} | a \in H\}$ and $\text{Orb}(gHg^{-1})$ may not necessarily be equal to $gHg^{-1}$. However, it should have size $1$, which means that $\text{Orb}(gHg^{-1})$ should in fact be equal to $gHg^{-1}$.

For reference, this result came from Rotman's Theorem 4.6, where no extra conditions were imposed on $H$ and $G$ except that $H$ is a subgroup of the $p$-group $G$ ... What am I missing here?

Comment: "Shouldn't this mean that $\text{Orb}(gHg^{-1})=\{agHg^{-1}a^{-1} | a \in H\}$" - Yes, it does mean that. Why does this seem problematic? For this to hold, it suffices that all elements of $H$ commute with $g$. This can certainly happen, e.g. if $H$ is in the center of $G$. Consider what happens if $G$ is abelian, for example.

Comment: @Bungo, thanks, but when I read the theorem 4.6 from where this came from (from Rotman's Theory of Groups), it only assumed that $H$ is a finite subgroup of the $p$-group $G$ with no other conditions ...

Comment: $Orb(gHg^{-1})$ of size 1 just means that $agHg^{-1}a^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$ for all $a \in H$. That can happen even if $g \ne e$. Are you asking how to prove that there are always are at least $p$ orbits of size 1?

Comment: @PedroAmaral, yes that if I could get some explanation on why there are at least $p$ orbits of size $1$, then it should help answer my question

Comment: If $H$ is normal in $G$, then $|X| = 1$, and the claim is false. If we assume that $H$ is not normal, then $|X| = [G:N_G(H)] > 1$. Since $N_G(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is a $p$-group, this means that $|X|$ is divisible by $p$. Now take the class equation: $|X| = \text{# of one-point orbits} + \sum (\text{sizes of nontrivial orbits})$. The LHS and the sizes of any nontrivial orbits are all divisible by $p$, hence so is the # of one-point orbits.

Comment: Btw, there's an error in Rotman's proof of Theorem 4.6. He says: "Now $G$ acts on $X$ by conjugation..." which is of course true but it's not the action he needs (that yields a transitive action, i.e. only one orbit, which is fine but useless in this context). He should have written: "Now $N_G(H)$ acts on $X$ by conjugation..." in which case the rest of the proof is OK. See [this old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102975/proof-of-p-groups-are-nilpotent-theorem-in-rotmans-theory-of-groups) about the same proof.

Comment: @Bungo, thanks, that cleared things up ! ... I think to understand the result I'll have to accept "by faith" that there's a size $1$ orbit of the form $gHg^{-1}$, but as to what $gHg^{-1}$ cannot be constructed directly without more info

Comment: Yeah, it's an existence proof but doesn't tell you *which* conjugates of $H$ will have size 1 orbits. For that, you probably need more details about the specific $p$-group $G$ and subgroup $H$. Looks like @PedroAmaral has provided an answer, so I'll refrain from expanding my comments into another similar answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to note is that if $|X| = 1$ then we will not have $p-1$ other orbits so we will also need to assume $|X| \gt 1$.

We will use these two properties of orbits to prove our statement:

1. Orbits are disjoint and their union is the entire set $X$ (this should be easy to see).
2. The orbit size divides group order (this is proven in the Orbit-stabilizer theorem)

By property (1) we have that $$|X| = \sum_{Y \in \mathcal{O}} |Y|$$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the set containing all the orbits of the action. Now we split $\mathcal{O}$ into two disjoint subsets: $\mathcal{O'}$ and $\mathcal{O''}$ where $\mathcal{O'}$ is the set of all orbits of size $1$ and $\mathcal{O''}$ is the set of all orbits of size greater than $1$. This means $$|X| = \sum_{Y' \in \mathcal{O'}} |Y'| + \sum_{Y'' \in \mathcal{O'}} |Y''| = |\mathcal{O'}| + \sum_{Y'' \in \mathcal{O'}} |Y''|$$ since $|Y'| = 1$. By property (2) we know that $|Y''|$ divides $|X| = p^n$ and $|Y''| > 1$ which means that $|Y''| = p^k$ where $k > 1$ which means $p$ divides $|Y''|$. We can view $X$ as an orbit where the group action is conjugation by the group $G$. This means that $|X|$ divides $|G| = p^n$. Since $|X| > 1$ we have that $p$ divides $|X|$. Since $|X| =  |\mathcal{O'}| + \sum_{Y'' \in \mathcal{O'}} |Y''|$, $p$ also has to divide $|\mathcal{O'}|$ which means $|\mathcal{O'}| = pm$ for some $m \gt 1$ which means $|\mathcal{O'}| \geq p$ which is what we were trying to prove.